# extract strings with some exceptions

Tags: r, regex

I have a bunch of strings with this kind of pattern:

```
w <- c("milan 01", "New York", "las vegas 123", "London abc")
```

I'd like to extract only the city name, that is either the first string or the first two strings with a space in between.

But I also have to make an exception on the cases like `"London"`.

(To simplify the problem I could pass to the regex the string `"abc"` as an exception).

I've done this:

```
library(stringr)

str_extract(w, "^\\S*\\s+(\\S+)")
#[1] "milan 01"   "New York"   "las vegas"  "London abc"

str_extract(w, "^\\S*\\s+(\\S+)(\\D)") # can't understand why this won't work
#[1] NA           "New York"   "las vegas " "London abc"
```

Desired:

```
#[1] "milan"   "New York"   "las vegas"  "London"
```

Comment: keep in mind that I may not know which city has `"abc"`, I just know that there is one.

Comment: Then you need a negative lookahead `^[a-zA-Z]+(?: +(?!abc\\b)[a-zA-Z]+)?)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use

```
> library(stringr)
> w <- c("Milan 01", "New York", "Las vegas 123", "London abc")
> str_extract(w, "^\\p{L}+(?:\\s+(?!abc\\b)\\p{L}+)?")
# => [1] "milan"     "New York"  "las vegas" "London"
```

If the first word can't be `abc` either, add the lookahead to the beginning:

```
> str_extract(w, "^(?!abc\\b)\\p{L}+(?:\\s+(?!abc\\b)\\p{L}+)?")   
                   ^^^^^^^^^^
```

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `\\p{L}+` - 1+ letters (if you plan to only support ASCII, you may use `[a-zA-Z]+` instead)
- `(?:\\s+(?!abc\\b)\\p{L}+)?` - an optional sequence of

  - `\\s+` - 1+ whitespaces
  - `(?!abc\\b)` - no `abc` as a whole word is allowed immediately to the right of the current location
  - `\\p{L}+` - 1+ letters

A base R `sub` equivalent:

```
> sub("(?s)^(\\p{L}+(?:\\s+(?!abc\\b)\\p{L}+)?).*", "\\1", w, perl=TRUE)
> ## OR > sub("(?s)^(?!abc\\b)(\\p{L}+(?:\\s+(?!abc\\b)\\p{L}+)?).*", "\\1", w, perl=TRUE)
[1] "milan"     "New York"  "las vegas" "London"
```

Here, `(?s)` makes `.` match any chars including line breaks, the whole specific part is wrapped in capturing parentheses, and the match is replaced with the Group 1 value.

Comment: thank you, this works well. What if I didn't know the `"abc"` pattern? I would have to find all wrong patterns and add them I imagine, or is there another way?

Comment: @RLave You do not have to add them all, but you should know the pattern you want to exclude. Otherwise, regex can't be used.